# Is User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Necessary?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-identity

I've been doing some stuff with ASP.NET MVC for a while, but I was wondering what use User.Identity.IsAuthenticated has - do I always need to check this before I trust User.Identity.Name, or is IsAuthenticated useless in this scenario?

Should I do something like:

```
public string GetUserName()
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        return User.Identity.Name;
    else
        return null;
}
```

Or would:

```
public string GetUserName()
{
    return User.Identity.Name;
}
```

be fine? I usually use the first way (checking just to be sure), but I never really understood if that was necessary (as far as I can tell, the default MVC 5 template only checks it essentially to see if the user is logged in).

Thanks!

Comment: You wrote the same code twice.

Comment: oops...meant to delete part of it, thanks xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an anonymous user (`User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false`), `User.Identity.Name` will return an empty string so you probably don't need the check unless you really want to return `null` from your method.

Now if `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false` can happen on a given page entirely depends on how you implement authentication in your application.